# Problem with WordPress Posts PHP , how to display images?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code where I should retrieve data from api and display on wordpress posts.
I have faced with problem to displaying images on post as featured image
I'm not good with php so I think I have done something wrong in my code

```php
function my_function()
{
    $data = file_get_contents("http://datastorageuniversal.com/profiles_data");
    $response = json_decode($data, true);
    $item = $response['data'][0];
    $post_title = $item['name'];

    $address = $item["address"];
    $zip_city = $item["zip_city"];
    $race = $item["race"];
    $sex = $item["sex"];
    $eyes = $item["eyes"];
    $hair = $item["hair"];
    $height = $item["height"];
    $weight = $item["weight"];
    $bildate = $item["bildate"];
    $biltime = $item["biltime"];
    $hair = $item["hair"];
    $Charges = $item["Charges"];
    $image_url = $item['image_url'];
    $name = "ASLYN SMITH";
    $category_id = get_cat_ID('Arrests');
    $name_parts = explode(' ', $name);
    $last_name = array_pop($name_parts);
    $first_name = implode(' ', $name_parts);
    $new_name = $first_name . ', ' . $last_name;
    foreach ($Charges as $charges) {
        $description = $charges['description'];
        $charge_start = $charges['charge_start'];
        $charge_end = $charges['charge_end'];
        $department = $charges['department'];
        $court = $charges['court'];
        $date = $charges['date'];
        $time = $charges['time'];
        $bond = $charges['bond'];
        $image_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/' . basename($image_url);
        file_put_contents($image_path, file_get_contents($image_url));

        // Create attachment post for the image
        $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $image_path,
            'post_mime_type' => mime_content_type($image_path),
            'post_title' => basename($image_path),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $image_path);

        // Set the post's featured image

        $post_content = "$image_path<br>Name: $name\nAddress: $address\nZip City: $zip_city\nRace: $race\nSex: $sex\nEyes: $eyes\nHair: $hair\nHeight: $height\nWeight: $weight\nBirth Date: $bildate\nBirth Time: $biltime\nCharges: \nDescription: $description\nCharge start: $charge_start\nCharge end: $charge_end\nDepartment: $department\nCourt: $court\nDate: $date\nTime: $time\nBond: $bond";

        // Check if post already exists for current data
        $existing_post_id = get_posts(array(
            'meta_key' => 'data_hash',
            'meta_value' => md5(json_encode($item)),
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'fields' => 'ids'
        ));

        if (!empty($existing_post_id)) {
            // Post already exists, update post content
            $new_post_id = $existing_post_id[0];
            $new_post = array(
                'ID' => $new_post_id,
                'post_title' => $post_title,
                'post_content' => $post_content,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1, // replace with your desired author ID
                'post_type' => 'post', // replace with your desired post type
                'post_category' => implode(',', array($category_id))
            );

            wp_update_post($new_post);
            set_post_thumbnail($new_post_id, $attachment_id);
        } else {
            // Post does not exist, create new post
            $new_post = array(
                'post_title' => $post_title,
                'post_content' => $post_content,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1, // replace with your desired author ID
                'post_type' => 'post', // replace with your desired post type
                'post_category' => array($category_id)
            );
            $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

            // Save data hash as custom field to check for duplicates
            update_post_meta($new_post_id, 'data_hash', md5(json_encode($item)));
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_function');
```

I have tried to display them on `$post_conent` as `img src=` but in that case I got 404 error on console,

Answer (score 0):

Here first you have to do `wp_insert_post` and that ID you need to pass to the attachment as tagged to that post.

Also there are several conditions while uploading to WP media. You have to check the actual file shouldn't upload duplicate. So you can store external url for the attachments and recheck while with `meta_query`.

#### Try below Code

```
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ||  empty($post_id)) {
    return;
}

// Add Featured Image to Post
$image_url         = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url); // removing query string from url & Define the image URL here
$image_name       = basename($image_url);
$upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
$image_data       = file_get_contents($url); // Get image data
$unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename($upload_dir['path'], $image_name); // Generate unique name
$filename         = basename($unique_file_name); // Create image file name

// Check folder permission and define file location
if (wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

// Create the image  file on the server
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

// Check image file type
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null);

// Set attachment data
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Create the attachment
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $post_id);
update_post_meta($attach_id, 'feed_external_url', $url, true);

// And finally assign featured image to post
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);

// Include image.php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// Define attachment metadata
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file);

// Assign metadata to attachment
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
```